# jquery problem with open minicart

Tags: mini-cart

For open minicart on click i wrote:

```
<div class="mini-cart" style="cursor:pointer;"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
    $('.mini-cart').click(function(){
        $('.topCartContent').toggle();

    })
});
 </script>
```

but there is a problem in script jquery.
If i go down with the scroll, and then i go up, the script not work.
What the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that jQuery not found the class `.mini-cart` in DOM try run the script when document is ready:

```
<div class="mini-cart" style="cursor:pointer;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $('.mini-cart').click(function(){
                $('.topCartContent').toggle();
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/bk09sbba/3/

Comment: same problem.

the minicard open once yes and once no